# How to bind values with nested json?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I need to make two way binding with my json data, so if the value is changing in input it should also changind in `data` section. I think the only way to do it is `bind` directive.

But I can't understand how to get access to nested value. Example:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    my_dates:
    [
        {
          "2018-03-23": {
            "april": 10,
            "may": 9,
            "june": 8,
            "july": 7,
            "august": 6,
            "september": 5,
            "october": 4,
            "income_trips": "1234.00",
            "med_services": "123.00",
            "food_services": "12.00",
            "accom_services": "1.00",
            "collegium": "1234.00",
            "parking": "123.00",
            "wash": "12.00",
            "other": "1.00",
            "balance": "1234.00",
            "employees": 50,
            "season_employees": 20,
            "complaints": 0,
            "reviews": 0
          }
        }
    ]

  }
})
```

And my html:
    `<td v-model="my_dates"></td>`

How I can access to, for example: `{{my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['april']}}`

Then I planed to put in `td` `input` tag to make it's editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.js v-bind is used to [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) a tags attribute value to a property value.
If you want to render the property value in your template you'll need to use [interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations)

```
 <td>{{my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['april']}}</td>
```

In Vuejs you use v-model when you want to provide 2-way binding with an input source. So, in your case you just need to add v-model to your input

```
<input v-model="my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['april']" placeholder="date input" />
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    my_dates:
    [
        {
          "2018-03-23": {
            "april": 10,
            "may": 9,
            "june": 8,
            "july": 7,
            "august": 6,
            "september": 5,
            "october": 4,
            "income_trips": "1234.00",
            "med_services": "123.00",
            "food_services": "12.00",
            "accom_services": "1.00",
            "collegium": "1234.00",
            "parking": "123.00",
            "wash": "12.00",
            "other": "1.00",
            "balance": "1234.00",
            "employees": 50,
            "season_employees": 20,
            "complaints": 0,
            "reviews": 0
          }
        }
    ]

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input v-model="my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['april']"        placeholder="april" /></th>
          <th><input v-model="my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['may']"        placeholder="may" /></th>
          <th><input v-model="my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['june']"        placeholder="june" /></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['april']}}</td>
          <td>{{my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['may']}}</td>
          <td>{{my_dates[0]['2018-03-23']['june']}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</main>
```